# How to calculate potential in circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage

In the following circuit (that has come up during a BJT DC analysis for what is worth), I'd like to calculate the potential at point B and point E.

My notes say that $V_B = -10 + 0.7 = -9.3V$. Trivial as it may seem, I can't understand it. The only way that I can think of is that the negative pole of the source is at $-10V$ and since there is a potential difference of $0.7V$ between the poles of the source, then the positive one must be at $-10 + 0.7 = -9.3V$.

I think that the presence of $-10V$ and GND is that confused me. What would be the potential of GND here ? Zero or something else ? If my understanding is sound, then the GND must have the same potential as $V_B$, which is $-9.3V$.

Any insights ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the potential of GND here ?

GND is the reference node which, by definition, measures 0V.  To see this, consider that *every one of the node voltages in the circuit are referenced to the GND node*.

In other words, if you wish to physically measure the voltage at a node in the circuit, you connect the black lead of your voltmeter to the GND node and your red lead to the node your wish to find the voltage of.

Clearly, if you put the red lead on the GND node, you've connected the red and black leads together and thus, you will read 0V there.

So, at the node that is labelled $-10V$, the voltmeter placed between that node and GND will read $-10V$.  If you move the red lead to node B, you will measure $-9.3V$ since, given the voltage source between the two nodes, *node B must be $0.7V$ more positive than the $-10V$ node.*

> But there's no current flowing through R1

There *must* be a current through $R_1$ since there is $-9.3V$ volts across it.  The current is 'up' through the resistor, 'up' through the $0.7V$ source and through the $-10V$ source (not shown) back to GND.

I think your confusion lies with the $-10V$ node - it appears to be disconnected but, in fact, *it is assumed that there is a $-10V$ voltage source connected there*.

Comment: The last line cleared things out for me. I wasn't aware that the -10V originated from a source that was connected there, so I thought that the whole circuit was 'open'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand it in this way: if we apply KVL along the branch containing $R$1 , the 0.7 $V$ battery and the -10 $V$ point, we will come to this very equation:

-10 + 0.7 = $V$ B

Now your confusion: Ground is always at 0. and the resistance is between GND and $V$B. Hence GND and $V$B are not at same potential as the resistance will contribute to a voltage drop too!

Comment: Re KVL ok got it.But there's no current flowing through $R_1$, so there shouldn't be any drop voltage along the resistance. Or?

Comment: If there is a potential difference in the circuit( which is completed due to presence of GND) of course there will be current flowing through the resistance. Unless you have a switch, which i cannot see.